# Email Users Daily with Content Containing Terms Also in User Profile

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, rules, users, emails

Users on my site add their "interests" via an autocomplete term reference field on a Profile2 form (adding to the "Interests" vocabulary).  I would like to send the users a daily email of content tagged with those same terms listed in their profile.

- I would also like to format this content a bit so it is aesthetically appealing - rather than just plain links to the related content.  Maybe something like themed 'teasers' for the content.
- I would like to just show the 2 most recent posts for 2 different types of content (both having the matching "interest" terms to the user, of course).
- I have a view set up that currently displays the above information in a block, but again I would like this as a daily email.  I thought this view could maybe just be inserted in rules, but this seems not to work as the contextual filter is based off the 'logged in user'

I was thinking this could be accomplished through Rules, but I have not yet figured out the right arrangement.  Or perhaps a modified daily simnplenews newsletter with a view insert could work?